# javascript - put layer in foreground leaflet

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, layer, foreground

I have different layer's arrays, but I want to put one of these in foreground when I change it latitude and longitude.
How I can do that in javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Browse over to the trusty Leaflet documentation, and look at the [setZIndex()](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-setzindex) function on all tile layers.

```
layer1.setZIndex(1);
layer2.setZIndex(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your layer is Raster or Vector.

For layers inheriting from Path, such as Polylines, Polygons, etc use `bringToFront`

```
layer.bringToFront()
```

For TileLayers (and layer types that inherit from TileLayers) use `setZIndex`

```
layer.setZIndex(<number>)
```